# How do I use Pillow's Image.convert() with a custom color palette?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to reduce the bit depth (color depth) of an image down to a set of custom colours in Python. Essentially to give the program a set of x colors and have it associate each pixel in a full color image with the closest color from the given list. I am having trouble with the Pillow library as evidenced below.

This code will correctly reduce the colors in image 'Z.png' down to only 4 colors, based on a palette of colors created from the image itself:

```
from PIL import Image

colorImage = Image.open("Z.png")
imageWithColorPalette = colorImage.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=4)
imageWithColorPalette.save("Output.png")

from IPython.display import Image
Image('Output.png')
```

This code is similar except I have attempted to use my own color palette. The problem is this code returns the exact same image as the above code and seems to just go with an adaptive palette and ignore the custom one I have attempted to specify:

```
from PIL import Image

pall = [
    0, 0, 0,
    255, 0, 0,
    255, 255, 0,
    255, 153, 0,
]

colorImage = Image.open("Z.png")
imageWithColorPalette = colorImage.convert("P", palette=pall, colors=4)
imageWithColorPalette.save("Output.png")

from IPython.display import Image
Image('Output.png')
```

Based on the documentaion from here:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert
and here
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImagePalette.html. I assume my *pall* is given in an incorrect format/size or that I need to include a *matrix* argument in the *convert* method. According to the documentation the *matrix* argument is **'An optional conversion matrix. If given, this should be 4- or 12-tuple containing floating point values.'** which I am unsure how to implement.

Whatever the problem is I'm very stuck and would appriciate some help.

Alternativley, is there a better Python library to use for this task as I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is along the lines of what you want

```
from PIL import Image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    palette = [
        159, 4, 22,
        98, 190, 48,
        122, 130, 188,
        67, 153, 0,
    ]

    img = Image.open('img.jpg')
    
    p_img = Image.new('P', (16, 16))
    p_img.putpalette(palette * 64)

    conv = img.quantize(palette=p_img, dither=0)
    conv.show()
```

Comment: Why did you change the palette from the one given in the question?

Comment: @MarkRansom just testing the code... it can be changed to whatever list of ints you want

Comment: Works great as long as I use a jpg not png. Is it the case that a palette must always be 768 long, therefore if I wanted to use something like 5 colors which doesn't divide nicely into 768 I could just copy the first 3 values in the list as many times as needed to reach 768 in length? Thanks.